# Fatal exception in Update thread , Array Index out of bound Invalid index 3709 size is 3709 in andEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I create simple game application . in which i used one animation Listener in onUpdate() method
like below code ::

```
animated_gift. setPosition( (gift.getX() + gift.getWidth()/2 - animated_gift.getWidth()/2), 
            (gift.getY() + gift.getHeight()/2 - animated_gift.getHeight()/2));
                        mainScene.attachChild(animated_gift);

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                animated_gift.animate(gift_animation_duration , false , new IAnimationListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationEnd(AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite) {
                                        animated_gift.detachSelf();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
```

but it gives me error : Fatal Exception in Update thread
            Array index out of bound  Invalid Index (some integer number) size is (some integer number)

In update method another animations also exists.
please help me how to resolve it .

Comment: I found it :: use only activity.this.runOnUpdateThread(....)method

Comment: Please do not add the answer as a comment.  Add your answer as and answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found solution of my above question. I use just `activity.this.runOnUpdateThread(...)` instead of `runOnUiThread(...)`.